# While getting user input, I set the smallest and largest numbers input into their own variables, but for whatever reason they start out = to 0

Tags: c++

While getting user input, I set the smallest and largest numbers input into their own variables, but for whatever reason they start out = to 0.

Code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int num;
    string var;
    int sum = 0;
    int i;
    int largest = INT_MIN;
    int smallest = INT_MAX;
    int j = 0;
    int prime = 0;
    do {
        cout << "Please enter a series of numbers, press (Q or q) to process: ";
        cin >> num;
        if (cin.fail())
        {
            cin.clear();
            cin >> var;
            if (var != "Q" && var != "q")
            {
                cout << "Invalid input, try again" << endl;
            }

        }
        if (num > largest)
        {
            largest = num;
        }
        if (num < smallest)
        {
            smallest = num;
        }
        if (num == 0 || num == 1)
        {
            prime = prime;
        }
        else
        {
            for (i = 2; i <= num / 2; i++)
            {
                if (num % i == 0)
                {
                    j = 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (j == 0)
            {
                prime++;
            }
        }
        sum += num;
        cout << "The corresponding element for the cumulative total sequence is: " << sum << endl;
        cin.ignore(sum, '\n');
    } while (var != "Q" && var != "q");
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Largest number: " << largest << endl;
    cout << "Smallest number: " << smallest << endl;
    cout << "How many prime numbers? " << prime << endl;
    cout << "Have a great day!" << endl;
}
```

Here is an example of the program being run.
[Program example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4evoM.png)

The smallest number here should be 8, and the issue is that it begins at 0. The same thing with the largest number.
[Program example #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfdGP.png)

Comment: You must post output as copy-pasted text, not as images. As for your program: you will have an easier time if you split your code into smaller chunks, aka into functions. Also you need to be able to debug your own program. It is immensely helpful and really an indispensable skill.

Comment: I set largest == INT_MIN, rather than INT_MAX. Same thing with the smallest.

Comment: right. My bad .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop is testing the "num" variable even if the user inputs q or Q, adding an else statement `else break;` after the `if (var != "Q" && var != "q")` will fix it.
For the future, always keep in mind that when the "if" function fails, it will move on to the next line, if you need to to not execute, you either need to break out of the loop or change the structure of your code.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it. So whenever they input q to quit at the end it set it as a 0?

Comment: basically yeah, because even if the IF wasnt activated, it went on to complete the other instructions